# Import dependencies issues in nest for Bull Queue modulein Node/nestjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs

i am trying to import queue service of bull mq module into one of my api

these are service file & module file of queue that i created

```
// queue.module.ts

import { BullModule } from '@nestjs/bullmq';
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { QueueService } from './queue.service';

@Module({
  imports: [
    BullModule.forRoot({
      connection: {
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 6379,
      },
    }),
    BullModule.registerQueue({
      name: 'queue',
    }),
  ],
  providers: [QueueService],
})
export class QueueModule { }


//queue.service.ts
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Queue } from 'bull';
import { InjectQueue } from '@nestjs/bull';

@Injectable()
export class QueueService {
  constructor(
    @InjectQueue('queue') private queue: Queue,
  ) { }

  async addImmediateJob(jobData: any) {
    await this.queue.add('immediateJob', jobData);
  }

  async addDelayedJob(
    jobData: any,
    delay: number,
  ) {
    await this.queue.add('delayedJob', jobData, {
      delay,
    });
  }

  async addRecurrentJob(
    jobData: any,
    cron: string,
  ) {
    await this.queue.add(
      'recurrentJob',
      jobData,
      { repeat: { cron } },
    );
  }
  async addPriorityJob(
    jobData: any,
    priority: number,
  ) {
    await this.queue.add('priorityJob', jobData, {
      priority,
    });
  }
  async addLimitedAttemptJob(
    jobData: any,
    attempts: number,
  ) {
    await this.queue.add(
      'limitedAttemptJob',
      jobData,
      { attempts },
    );
  }
  async getJob(jobId: string) {
    return await this.queue.getJob(jobId);
  }

  async updateJob(jobId: string, newData: any) {
    const job = await this.getJob(jobId);
    if (job) {
      await job.update(newData);
    }
  }

  async removeJob(jobId: string) {
    const job = await this.getJob(jobId);
    if (job) {
      await job.remove();
    }
  }
}
```

this module i am importing in main app

```
import { Module, NestModule, MiddlewareConsumer } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';


import { QueueModule } from './queue/queue.module';
import { QueueApiModule } from './queue-api/queue-api.module';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true,
    }),
    QueueModule,

    QueueApiModule,
  ],
  controllers: [ServiceCustomerController],
})
export class AppModule implements NestModule {
  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
 
  }
}
```

at this point if i dont import service somewhere not getting errors,but if i import in test api like this

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { QueueApiController } from './queue-api.controller';
import { QueueService } from '../queue/queue.service'


@Module({
  controllers: [QueueApiController],
  providers: [QueueService]
})
export class QueueApiModule { }
```

test api controller

```
import { Controller, Logger, Get } from '@nestjs/common';
import { QueueService } from '../queue/queue.service'


@Controller('queue-api')
export class QueueApiController {
    constructor(private readonly queueService: QueueService) { }

    @Get('addJob')
    async addJob() {
        try {
            await this.queueService.addImmediateJob({ message: 'Hello, World!' });
            return 'Job added to the queue: immediateJob';
        } catch (error) {
            Logger.error(`Error adding job: ${error.message}`);
            throw error;
        }
    }
}


then i am getting error like this

[Nest] 1158790  - 09/04/2023, 9:52:18 PM     LOG [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
[Nest] 1158790  - 09/04/2023, 9:52:18 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] BullModule dependencies initialized +59ms
[Nest] 1158790  - 09/04/2023, 9:52:18 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] JwtModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 1158790  - 09/04/2023, 9:52:18 PM   ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the QueueService (?). Please make sure that the argument BullQueue_queue at index [0] is available in the QueueApiModule context.

Potential solutions:
- Is QueueApiModule a valid NestJS module?
- If BullQueue_queue is a provider, is it part of the current QueueApiModule?
- If BullQueue_queue is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within QueueApiModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing BullQueue_queue */ ]
  })

Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the QueueService (?). Please make sure that the argument BullQueue_queue at index [0] is available in the QueueApiModule context.

Potential solutions:
- Is QueueApiModule a valid NestJS module?
- If BullQueue_queue is a provider, is it part of the current QueueApiModule?
- If BullQueue_queue is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within QueueApiModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing BullQueue_queue */ ]
  })

    at Injector.lookupComponentInParentModules (/home/sp/Desktop/profiling/server/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:247:19)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at Injector.resolveComponentInstance (/home/sp/Desktop/profiling/server/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:200:33)
    at resolveParam (/home/sp/Desktop/profiling/server/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:120:38)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at Injector.resolveConstructorParams (/home/sp/Desktop/profiling/server/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:135:27)
    at Injector.loadInstance (/home/sp/Desktop/profiling/server/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:61:13)
    at Injector.loadProvider (/home/sp/Desktop/profiling/server/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:88:9)
    at /home/sp/Desktop/profiling/server/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/instance-loader.js:49:13
    at async Promise.all (index 3)
```

i have checked all file locations in imports,everythings seems correct